# is_file and very long file names

Tags: php

Running local dev on Windows 7 64 bit, PHP 5.4.

I have an issue with `is_file()`. Given 2 **existing** files, here's what happens:

```
$file1 = "...."; // 189 characters file path
$file2 = "...."; // 265 characters file path

is_file($file1); // returns true
is_file($file2); // returns false
```

What's the problem? Is there a limit for file names?

On Linux production the problem doesn't exist, even with name length more than 256 characters.

Thank you.

Comment: How on earth do you end up with a 265 character long file name? The text should be put *in* the file...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It's the whole path, not just the file name. Moderately deep directory nesting with long-ish names (common for local dev environment) can make that happen easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows limits a single path to 260 characters: [File names and file name extensions: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7)

> **How long can a file name be?**
>  It depends on the length of the complete
>   path to the file (such as C:\Program Files\filename.txt). Windows
>   limits a single path to 260 characters. This is why you might
>   occasionally get an error when copying a file with a very long file
>   name to a location that has a longer path than the file's original
>   location.

This was the first result in Google for `windows 7 filename length`.

Answer (score 0):

`is_file()` returns false if the parent directory doesn't have +x (running permissions) set for the user running the php file.

Font: [is_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)